# intellij artifacts not created

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, ear, project-structure

I hope somebody can help me on this, I was given some sources to set the development environment but I cannot figure out what kind of project this is, the structure of the folders is like this:

```
TESTPROJECT
.idea
lib
META-INF
   application.xml
src
   classes
test-src
   testclasses
web
   faces
   resources
   WEB-INF
     faces-config.xml
     web.xml
here goes the iml
```

I am not sure what kind of project this is, I am opening as module in IntelliJ and as project but I am not sure how this has to be opened, but I am not able to build it or even generate any artifact, as they are not generated automatically, i would need the war or the ear but whenever i generate those manually they end up being corrupted or something is missing, I am not sure how to set up this environment so that I can make some changes and deploy back :S

Comment: Perhaps delete the iml file and .idea dir, and try to open it as a project.

Comment: but i would need a .project, which i dont have. so im not sure on that, any other idea?

Comment: Why don't you just open this as a project? This seems to be a complete project configuration. As for the artifacts, IntelliJ doesn't always generate them when you build the project; it's normal that you need to request those to be generated manually.